# Aggregate data with same date field

Tags: r, aggregation

I Have a large dataframe with similar dates in a column but different observations for those. I would like to average the rows with similar dates and generate an xts series out of it. My dataframe looks like the below:

```
SURVEY.DATE          A  B   C
1898    2010-05-13  38  34  21
1899    2010-05-13  38  33  21
1897    2010-05-14  37  34  21
1895    2010-05-21  38  29  21
1896    2010-05-21  39  32  21
1894    2010-05-23  39  32  21
```

and I would like to generate a xts object as follows:

```
            A    B      C
2010-05-13  38   33.5  21
2010-05-14  37   34    21
2010-05-21  38.5 30.5  21
2010-05-23  39   32    21
```

Probably trivial, but I am an R  newbie...Any help or pointer appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

A few notes - the date column has to be a proper `Date` type (note the `as.Date()` where I set up the dummy data in `mydf`).

If your data column `SURVEY.DATE` is a string, you'll need to do `as.Date()` on it for this to work.

The first step aggregates to get the mean - the `. ~ SURVEY.DATE' notation - in English means something like "everything else against SURVEY.DATE".

The second step turns it into an `xts` object.

I've left the `print` statements in so that you can see each stage working.

```
require(xts)

# set up and print the eample data
mydf <- data.frame(SURVEY.DATE = as.Date(c("2010-05-13", "2010-05-13", "2010-05-14", "2010-05-21", "2010-05-21", "2010-05-23")), A = c(38,38,37,38,39,39), B = c(34,33,34,29,32,32), C = c(21,21,21,21,21,21))
print(mydf)

# aggregate the dataframe by the SURVEY.DATE column
outdf <- aggregate(. ~ SURVEY.DATE, mydf,FUN=mean)
print(outdf)

# turn the dataframe into an xts object and print
outxts <- xts(outdf[,-1], order.by=outdf[,1])
print(outxts)
```